# Testing Stripe's trial_will_end webhook

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks, laravel-8, subscription

I'm in a bit of a pickle

I want to create a webhook listener to Stripe's `customer.subscription.trial_will_end` event to send a customer an email letting them know billing will start and giving them cancellation info, but I can't work out how to test it works without waiting a day between each test, i.e. setting the trial period for 4 days, and the event being fired when there's 3 days left.

The Stripe docs [give a method for testing trials](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing#trials), but this doesn't fit my use case as the only thing that doesn't work using that method is the `trial_will_end` event. The CLI can send webhook events, but again the `trial_will_end` event is not implemented.

How can I test this functionality without having to wait a full day between tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not currently great ways to manage time-dependent events like this. You will need to seed some test data to generate such events. For a given day of testing through, you can re-use a recent `trial_will_end` event (say `evt_123`) using the CLI `resend` function ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/events/resend)):

`stripe events resend evt_123 --webhook-endpoint we_321`

This will let you re-test your endpoint to handle the event & send the email multiple times, ingesting the same event.

Comment: Genius - do webhook events expire, or can I resend them indefinitely?

Comment: You can access events up to 30 days old via the API which is the limit for being able to use them here, too.